# Как узнать координаты курсора мыши относительно левого верхнего угла экрана на java?

Tags: java, windows, координаты, мышь, курсор

Здравствуйте. Пишу программу на java для windows. Надо узнать координаты курсора мыши относительно левого верхнего угла экрана.

Comment: `MouseEvent e; e.getX(); e.getY();` Вы про это?

Comment: Тут ещё наткнулся вот на такой инструмент org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде так:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        Point mouseLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        double x = mouseLocation.getX();
        double y = mouseLocation.getY();
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение на JavaFX.

Работать будет только в границах окна.

Но выдавать будет именно координаты на экране.

```
scene.setOnMouseMoved((mme)->{
    System.out.println(mme.getScreenX() + ":" + mme.getScreenY());
});
```